# Set Volume to NOT delete on termination on AWS EC2 Management Console

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

I want to make my one of my instance's hard drive (root) persistent so I can use it if I want to recreate it in the future, but I can' find the option anywhere.

Also, would it be possible to launch more than one instance from the same volume? (I tried creating an image from it but it didn't work although the image was created...)

Comment: It seems this link explains how to do what I want: http://scn.sap.com/community/developer-center/hana/blog/2013/06/23/preventing-the-deletion-of-ebs-volumes-during-the-termination-of-aws-spot-instances

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to have your root drive persist (kind-of) you need to start your AWS instance as EBS backed. On startup this will create an EBS disk that will be used as your root disk. Please note that this disk will incur charges.

Comment: my workaround was a little bit convoluted but less expensive: I created an ami image from the instance which created a snapshot I used to launch another instance (using the ami) unsetting "delete volume on termination", and when the instance terminates the volume is still there. If I make a snapshot of this volume I can attach it to a new instance and repeat the whole process (I know it's absurd to do this just to save a few bucks, but I guess tinkering with AWS is the best way to learn to use them...)

Answer (score 1):

You should use an AMI when you want to generate other instances.  However, the root EBS volume attached to the instance at statup will, by default, be deleted when you terminate.  If you want to change the DeleteOnTermination flag after you've launched your instance then you can check [here](http://frankwilsonv3.blogspot.com/2015/01/setting-aws-ec2-instance-attribute.html).

Comment: Could you provide info from the link here to maintain your answer if the link goes stale?